# How to customize scroll bar in Angular application

Tags: html, css, angular, scrollbar

I want to customize scroll bar for the whole application. Which means I want to change the default browser look on scroll bar. In my styles.scss file I have tried but saw no difference in scroll bar:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
   //changes
}

html::-webkit-scrollbar {
  //changes
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  //changes
}

::ng-deep ::-webkit-scrollbar {
  //changes
}
```

app.component.html:

```
<app-shell>
   <main>
       <router-outlet></router-outlet>
   </main>
</app-shell>
```

shell.component.html:

```
<nav>
<!-- navbar here -->
</nav>

<main>
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</main>
```

Is there something that I misunderstood about scrollbars? How to change the browser default scroll bar around the application?

UPDATE: Even if there is nothing to scroll on the page, there is white scrollbar on the right side.

Answer (score 4):

I have used many times these code lines:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
   width: 0; /* Remove scrollbar space */
   background: transparent; /* Optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
   background: #FF0000;
}
```

They worked for me in many situations.

Try using `!important` or specifying the div in which the scrollbar is rendering (I needed this is some cases)

```
.your-div-selector::-webkit-scrollbar {
   width: 0; /* Remove scrollbar space */
   background: transparent; /* Optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
}

.your-div-selector::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
   background: #FF0000;
}
```

Comment: I tried adding !important but it didn't change anything. Which div should I specify in order to apply changes to the whole app?

Comment: Try something like: 

`div::-webkite-scrollbar { ... }` this allows to add that style to every div. But I think you may need to do it for each scrollable div with a particular selector

Comment: I tried div.class-name::webkit-scrollbar { ... } but it did not make any difference. I tested the div.class-name selector so the selector is correct but it just does not affect scrollbar.